# java string matching problem

Tags: java

I am facing a very basic problem. Some time small things can take your whole day :(
but thank to stackoverflow memebers who always try to help :)

I am trying to match 2 strings if they match it should return TRUE

now I am using this

```
if (var1.indexOf(var2) >= 0) {
return true;
}
```

But if var1 has value "maintain" and var2 has value "inta" or "ain" etc. it still return true :(.
Is there any way in java that can do full text matching not partial? 
For example

```
if("mango"=="mango"){
return true;
}
```

thanks ! ! !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just use the built-in String `equals()` method?

```
return var1.equals(var2);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if( "mango".equals("mango") ) { 
   return true;
}
```

Be careful not to use == for string comparisons in Java unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: == is comparing what the references point to, and .equals in the case of String is comparing the Strings lexicographically.  In Java, you can create two new Strings that have the same content, and == will return false.  In the contrived example you wrote, using == will most likely appear to work correctly, but if you created two String variables with the new operator and set the value to mango, it wouldn't work.

Comment: Here's a very rough analogy: `var1 == var2` is like asking if two people are the same person, while `var1.equals(var2)` is like asking if two people have the same name.

Answer (score 3):

use `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase` on `java.util.String` for matching strings. You also need to check for `null` on the object you are comparing, I would generally prefer using `commons` [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) for these purposes. It has very good utils for common string operations.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example to show why `==` is not what you want:

```
String s1 = new String("something");
String s2 = new String("something");
System.out.println(s1 == s2);
System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));
```

In effect, while `s1` and `s2` contains the same sequence of characters, they are not referring to the same location in memory. Thus, this prints `false` and `true`.